# Grouping 2D numpy array in average

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to group a numpy array into smaller size by taking average of the elements. Such as take average foreach 5x5 sub-arrays in a 100x100 array to create a 20x20 size array. As I have a huge data need to manipulate, is that an efficient way to do that?

Comment: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645013/windowed-maximum-in-numpy/18645174#18645174) answer as well.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have tried this for smaller array, so test it with yours:

```
import numpy as np

nbig = 100
nsmall = 20
big = np.arange(nbig * nbig).reshape([nbig, nbig]) # 100x100

small = big.reshape([nsmall, nbig//nsmall, nsmall, nbig//nsmall]).mean(3).mean(1)
```

An example with 6x6 -> 3x3:

```
nbig = 6
nsmall = 3
big = np.arange(36).reshape([6,6])
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])

small = big.reshape([nsmall, nbig//nsmall, nsmall, nbig//nsmall]).mean(3).mean(1)

array([[  3.5,   5.5,   7.5],
       [ 15.5,  17.5,  19.5],
       [ 27.5,  29.5,  31.5]])
```

Comment: Here is a generalization to N-dimensional arrays https://stackoverflow.com/a/73078468/3753826

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty straightforward, although I feel like it could be faster:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
Norig = 100
Ndown = 20
step = Norig//Ndown
assert step == Norig/Ndown # ensure Ndown is an integer factor of Norig
x = np.arange(Norig*Norig).reshape((Norig,Norig)) #for testing
y = np.empty((Ndown,Ndown)) # for testing
for yr,xr in enumerate(np.arange(0,Norig,step)):
    for yc,xc in enumerate(np.arange(0,Norig,step)):
        y[yr,yc] = np.mean(x[xr:xr+step,xc:xc+step])
```

You might also find [scipy.signal.decimate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.decimate.html) interesting.  It applies a more sophisticated low-pass filter than simple averaging before downsampling the data, although you'd have to decimate one axis, then the other.

Answer (score 3):

Average a 2D array over subarrays of size NxN:

```
height, width = data.shape
data = average(split(average(split(data, width // N, axis=1), axis=-1), height // N, axis=1), axis=-1)
```

Comment: Nice one! Just a clarification that average and split are numpy funtions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that [eumiro's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624923/5703449) does not work for masked arrays as `.mean(3).mean(1)` assumes that each mean along axis 3 was computed from the same number of values. If there are masked elements in your array, this assumption does not hold any more. In that case, you have to keep track of the number of values used to compute `.mean(3)` and replace `.mean(1)` by a weighted mean. The weights are the normalized number of values used to compute `.mean(3)`.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np


def gridbox_mean_masked(data, Nbig, Nsmall):
    # Reshape data
    rshp = data.reshape([Nsmall, Nbig//Nsmall, Nsmall, Nbig//Nsmall])

    # Compute mean along axis 3 and remember the number of values each mean
    # was computed from
    mean3 = rshp.mean(3)
    count3 = rshp.count(3)

    # Compute weighted mean along axis 1
    mean1 = (count3*mean3).sum(1)/count3.sum(1)
    return mean1


# Define test data
big = np.ma.array([[1, 1, 2],
                   [1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1]])
big.mask = [[0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]]
Nbig = 3
Nsmall = 1

# Compute gridbox mean
print gridbox_mean_masked(big, Nbig, Nsmall)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`reduce()`](https://einops.rocks/api/reduce/) from the `einops` package:

```py
import numpy as np
from einops import reduce

m, n = 100, 20  # `nbig` and `nsmall` in the accepted answer
big = np.arange(m * m).reshape(m, m)
small = reduce(big.astype(float), "(a1 a2) (b1 b2) -> a1 b1", "mean", a1=n, b1=n)
```