# Downsize 3D Matrix by Averaging in Numpy or alike

Tags: numpy, matrix, scipy

Is there a simple way of reducing the size of a 3D matrix by averaging blocks of a certain size in *Numpy* or *Scipy* or even with NetC*D*F tools or something similar? I wrote a 2D one using strides a while back but a ready to use function would help a lot.

**Edit:**

Example of what I'd like my input and output to look like:

`Input's shape: (500, 500, 100)`

`Calling the function: downsize(input, 10, 10, 10, func)`

`Output's shape: (50, 50, 10)` where every cell's value is the result of `func` on consecutive 10x10x10 submatrices.

Alternatively, the code can get the desired matrix size as input instead of the size of the submatrices and figure them out.

Thanks

Comment: [`Scipy's imresize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html)?

Comment: @Divakar I think that only works for images because it says that the 3D matrix needs to be compatible with one of the `modes`. What I have is a 3D volume of virtually any possible size (e.g. 500x500x100).

Comment: Could you add a mcve on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an approach using reshaping to slice up each axis into two, thereby creating six axes and then performing merged averaging on the second sliced axes for each of the three original axis to get the blockwise averaging -

```
def blockwise_average_3D(A,S):    
    # A is the 3D input array
    # S is the blocksize on which averaging is to be performed

    m,n,r = np.array(A.shape)//S
    return A.reshape(m,S[0],n,S[1],r,S[2]).mean((1,3,5))
```

Sample runs -

```
In [107]: A = np.random.randint(0,255,(500,500,100)) # 3D Input array
     ...: S = (10,10,10)                             # Blocksize
     ...: 

In [108]: out = blockwise_average_3D(A,S)

In [109]: out[0,0,0]
Out[109]: 124.242

In [110]: A[:10,:10,:10].mean()
Out[110]: 124.242

In [111]: out[0,1,0]
Out[111]: 129.89400000000001

In [112]: A[:10,10:20,:10].mean()
Out[112]: 129.89400000000001
```

Comment: Wow, much shorter than my approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the records, here is a function that works for N-dimensional arrays, generalizing [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37534242/3753826)

```
import numpy as np

def blockwise_average_ND(a, factors):    
    """
    `a` is the N-dim input array
    `factors` is the blocksize on which averaging is to be performed
    """

    factors = np.asanyarray(factors)
    sh = np.column_stack([a.shape//factors, factors]).ravel()
    b = a.reshape(sh).mean(tuple(range(1, 2*a.ndim, 2)))

    return b
```

Examples

```
a = np.arange(192).reshape(4, 6, 8)
blockwise_average_ND(a, (2, 3, 4))

# array([[[ 33.5,  37.5],
#         [ 57.5,  61.5]],
#        [[129.5, 133.5],
#         [153.5, 157.5]]])

a = np.arange(135).reshape(15, 9)
blockwise_average_ND(a, (5, 3))

# array([[ 19.,  22.,  25.],
#        [ 64.,  67.,  70.],
#        [109., 112., 115.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up extending my 2D version to a 3D and apparently it works. Here it is in case someone else needs it too.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

# 3D version of my block view function
def block_view(arr, block_size):
    shape   = tuple(_shape / _bsize for _shape, _bsize in zip(arr.shape, block_size)) + block_size
    strides = tuple(_bsize * _stride for _bsize, _stride in zip(block_size, arr.strides)) + arr.strides

    return as_strided(arr, shape=shape, strides=strides)

def aggregate(arr, block_size):
    blocks = block_view(arr, block_size)
    dimension_offset = len(arr.shape)
    block_dimensions = range(dimension_offset, dimension_offset + len(block_size))
    for dim in block_dimensions:
        blocks = np.mean(blocks, axis=dim, keepdims=True)

    blocks = blocks[:, :, :, 0, 0, 0]
    return blocks
```

I tried to make it work for any N dimensional matrix but the only limitation is the `blocks = blocks[:, :, :, 0, 0, 0]` line.