# block mean of 2D numpy array (in both dimensions)

Tags: python, numpy

This question is related to [Block mean of numpy 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229029/block-mean-of-numpy-2d-array) (in fact the title is almost the same!) except that my case is a generalization.  I want to divide a 2D array into a sub-blocks in both directions and take the mean over the blocks.  (The linked example only divides the array in one dimension).

Thus if my array is this:

```
import numpy as np 
a=np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

If my sub-blocks have a size 2x2, then my desired answer is

```
array([[ 2.5,  4.5],
       [10.5, 12.5]])
```

The only way I could think of doing this was to carefully reshape on one dimension at a time:

```
np.mean(np.mean(a.reshape((2,2,-1)),axis=1).reshape((-1,2,2)),axis=2)
```

This gives the correct solution but is a bit of a convoluted mess, and I was wondering if there is a cleaner easier code to do the same thing, maybe some numpy blocking function that I am unaware of ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
# sample data
a=np.arange(24).reshape((6,4))

rows, cols = a.shape    
a.reshape(rows//2, 2, cols//2, 2).mean(axis=(1,-1))
```

Output:

```
array([[ 2.5,  4.5],
       [10.5, 12.5],
       [18.5, 20.5]])
```

Comment: double axis mean, of course (doh!) - nice the double forward slash for int(n/m) - I didn't know that either...  thanks!

Comment: See here for a generalization to N-dimensional arrays https://stackoverflow.com/a/73078468/3753826

Comment: @Quang my function `blockwise_average_ND` was generalized for any dimension as stated, not just 3D as you write. But if you found a bug please let me know.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was looking at the accepted answer.