# How to efficiently calculate block mean (irregular blocks) for numpy 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mean

My question is related to [Block mean of numpy 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229029/block-mean-of-numpy-2d-array) and [block mean of 2D numpy array (in both dimensions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66160734/block-mean-of-2d-numpy-array-in-both-dimensions) (in fact it is just more general case). I will explain this on simple example.

Let's assume we have `6x6` 2D array:

```py
array([[7, 1, 6, 6, 4, 2],
       [8, 5, 5, 6, 3, 5],
       [3, 1, 7, 1, 3, 4],
       [6, 8, 3, 2, 3, 3],
       [8, 6, 7, 1, 1, 3],
       [8, 5, 4, 5, 1, 4]])
```

Now  each row (and column) in this matrix is assigned to one of three communities (communities can be of different size) e.g. `array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2])` would represent this assignment. Now I need to split this matrix according this assignment and calculate mean over blocks (slices). This would produce `3x3` matrix of block means. For example block (or slice) for community pair (0,0) is an `2x2` array:

```py
array([[7, 1],
       [8, 5]])
```

that has mean of `5.25`. Block for community pair (0, 1) is an `2x3` array:

```py
array([[6, 6, 4],
       [5, 6, 3]])
```

with mean `5`, and so on..

Resulting array of block means should look like this:

```py
array([[5.25      , 5.        , 3.5       ],
       [5.33333333, 3.11111111, 3.33333333],
       [6.5       , 3.33333333, 4.        ]])
```

My question is how to calculate this efficiently. For now I am using for loops – for each pair of communities I get proper slice, calculate mean over that slice and store this in separate matrix. However I need to perform this operation many times and it takes a lot of time.

I cannot really use (or I dont know how) approaches with `reshape` since it needs an assumption of equal block size.

Comment: You should show the loop version.  It's a lot easier to test improvements against a working solution.  And less work for us if you provide that working solution.  I suspect the best we can do is tweak the solution around the edges.  As you say `numpy` solutions that depend on a regular pattern don't apply.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to other packages, `Pandas` as a convenient `groupby` function:

```
out = (pd.Series(a.ravel(), 
                  index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((pairs,pairs)))
         .groupby(level=(0,1)).mean()
         .unstack().to_numpy()
      )
```

Output:

```
array([[5.25      , 5.        , 3.5       ],
       [5.33333333, 3.11111111, 3.33333333],
       [6.5       , 3.33333333, 4.        ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can imagine is to try to limit the number of loops. I will assume here that the 6x6 2D array is `arr` and that the communities definition is `coms = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2])`.

I would first compute slices per community:

```
dcoms = {k: slice(min(x), 1 + max(x)) for k in np.unique(coms)
         for x in (np.where(coms==k)[0],)}
```

1 loop over `coms`

Then I can directly compute the resulting ndarray with 2 loops over `dcoms`:

```
resul = np.array([[arr[dcoms[i],dcoms[j]].mean() for j in dcoms] for i in dcoms])
```

It gives as expected:

```
array([[5.25      , 5.        , 3.5       ],
       [5.33333333, 3.11111111, 3.33333333],
       [6.5       , 3.33333333, 4.        ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I performed some benchmark tests to compare these solutions.

The setup is following

```py
np.random.seed(0)

mat = (np.random.random((500, 500)) - 0.5) * 100

# Create 5 communities of size 50 and 10 communities of size 15
comms = np.concatenate((np.repeat(np.arange(5), 50), np.repeat(np.arange(5, 15), 25)))
```

My original solution using for loops:

```py
unique_comms = np.unique(comms)
block = np.zeros((len(unique_comms), len(unique_comms)))
for i in unique_comms:
    for j in unique_comms:
        block[i, j] = np.mean(mat[comms == i][:, comms == j])
```

took **7.66 ms ± 43.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)**.

Pandas solution:

```py
out = (pd.Series(mat.ravel(), 
                  index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((comms, comms)))
         .groupby(level=(0,1)).mean()
         .unstack().to_numpy())
```

took **22.1 ms ± 221 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)**

whereas slice solution:

```py
dcoms = {k: slice(min(x), 1 + max(x)) for k in np.unique(comms)
         for x in (np.where(comms==k)[0],)}
resul = np.array([[mat[dcoms[i],dcoms[j]].mean() for j in dcoms] for i in dcoms])
```

took **2.1 ms ± 61.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)**.

Unfortunately Pandas solution is much slower, whereas slice solution is apparently ~3-4 fold faster than regular for loop solution. One drawback of slice solution is that (I believe) it does not work when community vector is shuffled (i.e. `np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1])` instead of `np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2])`.