# Windowed maximum in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array and I would like to produce a smaller array by scanning a 2x2 non-overlappingly windows and getting the maximum. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=1000,precision=3)
arr = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(4,4))
res = np.zeros((2,2))
for i in xrange(res.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(res.shape[1]):
        ii = i*2
        jj = j*2
        res[i][j] = max(arr[ii][jj],arr[ii+1][jj],arr[ii][jj+1],arr[ii+1][jj+1])

print arr
print res
```

So a matrix like this:

```
[[ 0.393 -0.428 -0.546  0.103]
 [ 0.439 -0.154  0.962  0.37 ]
 [-0.038 -0.216 -0.314  0.458]
 [-0.123 -0.881 -0.204  0.476]]
```

Should become this:

```
[[ 0.439  0.962]
 [-0.038  0.476]]
```

How can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and why it hasn't worked?

Comment: the code above does the required job, but this needs to be fast and therefore i would like to remove the for loop

Comment: Consider using [NumBa](http://numba.pydata.org/). You could leave your double loop just as it is, add about 10 characters in a decorator, and get C-like performance for this. Easy to use out-of-the-box if you work with Continuum Analytics' ["Anaconda"](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) distribution of Python.

Comment: The best answer is here in the comments! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645013/windowed-maximum-in-numpy#comment27454126_18645361

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
print arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(2,2,4).max(axis=-1)

[[ 0.439  0.962]
 [-0.038  0.476]]
```

To explain starting with:

```
arr=np.array([[0.393,-0.428,-0.546,0.103],
[0.439,-0.154,0.962,0.37,],
[-0.038,-0.216,-0.314,0.458],
[-0.123,-0.881,-0.204,0.476]])
```

We first want to group the axes into relevant sections.

```
tmp = arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).swapaxes(1,2)
print tmp    

[[[[ 0.393 -0.428]
   [ 0.439 -0.154]]

  [[-0.546  0.103]
   [ 0.962  0.37 ]]]


 [[[-0.038 -0.216]
   [-0.123 -0.881]]

  [[-0.314  0.458]
   [-0.204  0.476]]]]
```

Reshape once more to obtain the groups of data we want:

```
tmp = tmp.reshape(2,2,4)
print tmp

[[[ 0.393 -0.428  0.439 -0.154]
  [-0.546  0.103  0.962  0.37 ]]

 [[-0.038 -0.216 -0.123 -0.881]
  [-0.314  0.458 -0.204  0.476]]]
```

Finally take the max along the last axis.

This can be generalized, for square matrices, to:

```
k = arr.shape[0]/2
arr.reshape(k,2,k,2).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(k,k,4).max(axis=-1)
```

Following the comments of Jamie and Dougal we can generalize this further:

```
n = 2                   #Height of window
m = 2                   #Width of window
k = arr.shape[0] / n    #Must divide evenly
l = arr.shape[1] / m    #Must divide evenly
arr.reshape(k,n,l,m).max(axis=(-1,-3))              #Numpy >= 1.7.1
arr.reshape(k,n,l,m).max(axis=-3).max(axis=-1)      #Numpy <  1.7.1
```

Comment: Note that there's no reason the arrays need to be square, as long as they're divisible; you can change it to `k = arr.shape[0] / n; l = arr.shape[1] / n; arr.reshape(k, n, l, n).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(k, l, n*n).max(axis=-1)`, I think.

Comment: That last reshape after swapping the axes triggers a copy of the full array, which can be costly for large arrays. The best option is to skip it altogether and (using numpy > 1.7) give a tuple of axes to `.max`, i.e. `arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).max(axis=(-1, -3))` Even if you are stuck with an older version of numpy, you'll copy half the data if you make two calls to `.max`, i.e. `arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).max(axis=-3).max(axis=-1)`.

Comment: @Jaime, thanks.using numpy 1.7.1 and for arr of 40x40, `arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).max(axis=(-1, -3))` does not improve performance but `arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).max(axis=-3).max(axis=-1)` is about 1.5 times faster

Comment: @Dougal Good idea, can generalize it even further to arbitrary windows also!.

Comment: @Jamie Good point. Updated the final function, but kept the rest for the didactic explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comment area, consider using NumBa. You could leave your double loop just as it is, add about 10 characters in a decorator, and get C-like performance for this. Easy to use out-of-the-box if you work with Continuum Analytics' "Anaconda" distribution of Python.

This is almost a perfect use case for NumBa because this algorithm is much more naturally expressed with the double loop. The reshaping approach exploits fast array operations, but it's extremely unreadable unless you already know the goal of the program. It's highly desirable to leave functions like this in the expanded form and achieve speed by letting something else convert to a low-level language after the fact.

Comment: i am aware of numba and the corresponding speed, but i was looking for a pure numpy solution. thanks

Comment: I was curious about how well numba would actually do on this problem, so I gave it a shot: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/c22a894f260d17876f01. In my test of slightly-modified versions of these functions, on a 200x200 matrix, the original code took 100ms, the numba JIT'd version took ~85ms, and @Ophion's version took 0.5ms. Scaling up, on a 2k x 2k matrix numba took 8s and Ophion's took 64ms. ~150x speedups are probably worth a little loss in readability; do you know if I'm doing something wrong here causing numba to do so poorly?

Comment: Not sure, but for this sort of kernel, that sounds very unusual. I'll take a look at the notebook.

Comment: Actually, I rephrased the max as an array operation (because that's what seemed most natural); I just tried it as an explicit loop, which is more like OP's code anyway, and it's doing much better (about 4x as much time as Ophion's, instead of 125x). Updated the notebook.

Comment: Unfortunately, you do seem to have to write out the max-finding operation yourself; you can't call `max(arr[ii, jj] for ii in ... for jj in ...)` because generator expressions aren't supported, and doing it with a list comprehension gives a 6x slowdown.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: i think you should put 'nopython=True' somewhere,it forces you to fix this type of calling into python problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`reduce()`](https://einops.rocks/api/reduce/) from the `einops` package:

```py
res = reduce(arr, "(a1 a2) (b1 b2) -> a1 b1", "max", a2=2, b2=2)
```