# Numpy max pooling convolution

Tags: python, numpy

Edit:

What I actually wanted to do is finding local maxima, which is explained good below, and the same solution is also explained here:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_peak_local_max.html

---

---

---

It seems you can do [linear](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) convolution in Numpy.

Is it possible to do a non-linear max pooling convolution? Use a NxM patch and stride over the input image, zeroing the current pixel if it's not the maximum in the vicinity?

So a non-linear max convolution works like this, here is my image

```
  3 4 5 2 3
  3 5 1 2 7
  2 2 5 1 7
```

And given a 2x2 max pooling gives this output

```
  0 0 5 0 0
  0 5 0 0 7
  0 0 5 0 7
```

You have a 2x2 patch that strides over the image, and zeroes everything, only keeping the max value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windowed maximum in numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645013/windowed-maximum-in-numpy)

Comment: Added example, @Lanting the question you refer to is not a convolution

Comment: Shouldn't the output `(2,2)` be zero instead, as there's a bigger `6` in that sliding patch?

Comment: Also, how do you define a center pixel in a `(2,2)` patch? Don't you mean a `(3,3)` patch instead?

Comment: Well, maybe a 3x3 works better but I it seems the maximum-filter still can handle a 2x2 patch

Comment: @user1506145 It will work sure, but the center pixel would be ambiguous in  a 2x2 patch. Also, with maximum_filter and using `2X2` window size/footprint won't result in that listed expected output. Would make sense to make the edits in the question to reflect/discuss that, I would think.

Comment: Sure, my question is ambiguous, what I actually wanted to do is finding local maxima.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [Scipy's maximum_filer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter.html) -

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import maximum_filter

arr*(arr == maximum_filter(arr,footprint=np.ones((3,3))))
```

Sample run -

```
In [19]: arr
Out[19]: 
array([[3, 4, 5, 2, 3],
       [3, 5, 1, 2, 7],
       [2, 2, 5, 6, 7]])

In [20]: arr*(arr == maximum_filter(arr,footprint=np.ones((3,3))))
Out[20]: 
array([[0, 0, 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 5, 0, 0, 7],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 7]])
```

Comment: Perfect! Smart thing with the mask, otherwise the image would consist of plateaus. Your solution extract the local maximums, exactly what i needed :)