# Averaging arrays over a grid in Python

Tags: python, arrays, average

I would like to average a `d`-dimensional array `M` of size NxNx...xN (d times) over a regular grid of step `k`, i.e. building a new array `N` of size NxNx...xN (d times) where in each hypercube H of the regular grid of step k, the value of the array are all the same and equal to the average of H in the original array.

More clearly on example, for `d=2`, `N=4` and `k=2`:

```
M=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
```

and

```
N=[[1.5,1.5,3.5,3.5],[1.5,1.5,3.5,3.5],[1.5,1.5,3.5,3.5],[1.5,1.5,3.5,3.5]]
```

This related to an existing question : [Grouping 2D numpy array in average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624112/grouping-2d-numpy-array-in-average)
Yet, this only works for 2D array and not exactly outputs the array in the shape I want.

I have tried to implement it my self in the case of d=2, yet doing similarly for higher dimension would imply to repeat d-times for loops, which seems prohibitive (I don't see how to do it otherwise). I am sure there is a more compact and efficient way to do so.
My try for d=2 :

```py
def local_average_img(M,k):
  l=len(M[0])
  N = np.zeros((l,l))
  for x in range(l):
    for y in range(l):
      print(np.mean(M[(x//k)*k:(x//k)*k+k, (y//k)*k:(y//k)*k+k]))
      N[x][y]=np.mean(M[(x//k)*k:(x//k)*k+k, (y//k)*k:(y//k)*k+k])
  return(N)

M = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
k = 2
result = local_average_img(M, k)
print(result)
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @Freeman I have edited my original post providing my try (in dimension 2, I don't see how to generalize it avoiding d for loops imbricated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution below can help you. As you can see, you are not getting rid of all the looping (I would say that you cannot, but a man can dream). The pros are that the "heavy looping" is done to compute indexes, and form slices. Then the actual averaging is done in `numpy` which is faster than nesting `for` loops. Moreover, you do not have to adapt the code (e.g. adding/removing loops) when `d` changes.

```py
import itertools
import numpy as np

d = 2   # number of dimensions
n = 4   # size of each dimension
k = 2   # side of the hypercube to average in

# Define M input hypercube and initialize "empty" H hypercube
M = (np.random.rand(*[n for i in range(d)]) * 10).astype(int)
H = np.zeros(M.shape, dtype=np.float32)

# Compute the index of the first element in each sub-hypercube.
# In the 2D example, it is the top-left corner of the "square".
indexes = [i for i in range(n)
       if i % d == 0]
indexes = itertools.product(indexes, repeat = d)

for idx in indexes:
    # Also compute the index of the last element of the sub-hypercube.
    # In the 2D example, it is the bottom-right corner of the "square".
    idx_i = np.array(idx)
    idx_f = idx_i + k
    # Define a tuple of slices objects to index the sub-hypercube.
    nd_slice = []
    for dim in range(d):
        s = slice(idx_i[dim], idx_f[dim], 1)
        nd_slice.append(s)
    nd_slice = tuple(nd_slice)  
    # Compute the average in the sub-hypercube and substitute it to the current values.
    H[nd_slice] = np.mean(M[nd_slice])

print(M)
print(H)
```

**Disclaimer.** I am confident that the for loops can be made more efficient. Indeed, indexes are cast to `np.array` and then to `slices`, which are gathered in a `list` and finally converted to a `tuple`. To me, it looks too messy to be the optimal solution, but I am not able to make it better...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

### Basic idea

I would try to avoid all loops by the following approach:

- move the "grid cell" values (you call them `H` in the question, I will call them "patches" in the following code) into their own, separate array dimension,
- calculate the mean along this new dimension,
- bring the result back to the original size and shape.

### Pure Numpy solution

Using pure Numpy, this could look as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

def local_average(m: np.ndarray, k: int | tuple[int]) -> np.ndarray:
    m_shape, m_dims_x2 = np.asarray(m.shape), np.arange(2 * m.ndim)  # Reusable
    
    # Can `m` be split by the grid along each dimension without remainder?
    assert not np.any(m_shape % k)
    # Get shape of each grid-sized (hyper)cube within the total (hyper)cube `m`
    patch = (np.ones(m.ndim) * k).astype(int)
    # Get "remaining shape" of `m`, i.e. number of patches along each dim
    remaining = m_shape // patch

    # 1. Reshape: remaining size, patch size, remaining size, patch size, ...
    res = m.astype(float).reshape(*np.c_[remaining, patch].ravel())
    # 2. Transpose: remaining dims (even) first, patch dims (odd) last
    res = res.transpose(*m_dims_x2.reshape(-1, 2).T.ravel())
    # 3. Reshape: flatten patches along last dim
    res = res.reshape(*remaining, -1)
    # 4. Calculate mean along last dim (i.e. along flattened patch dim)
    means = res.mean(axis=-1)
    # 5. Expand to patch size: replace values in last dim of `res` with means
    res[:] = means[..., np.newaxis]
    # 6. Reverse steps 1–3 to get original shape
    res = res.reshape(*remaining, *patch)
    res = res.transpose(*m_dims_x2.reshape(2, -1).T.ravel())
    res = res.reshape(*m_shape)
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m_demo = np.arange(4 * 6 * 6).reshape(4, 6, 6)
    k_demo = 2
    print(m_demo)
    print(local_average(m=m_demo, k=k_demo))
```

If we assume a 6×8×10-shaped array `m` and a grid step of `k=2` for example, then the resulting shapes would be

- 3×2×4×2×5×2 in step 1 (alternating remaining dims and patch dims),
- 3×4×5×2×2×2 in step 2 (remaining dims first, patch dims last),
- 3×4×5×(2·2·2) = 3×4×5×8 in steps 3 and 5 (remaining dims first, patch dims flattened),
- 3×4×5 in step 4 (remaining dims only),
- 6×8×10 in step 6 (original shape).

### Solution with `einops`

Alternatively, by using the [`einops`](https://einops.rocks/) package, you can shorten the code, using [`reduce()`](https://einops.rocks/api/reduce/) to fuse steps 1–4 from above and [`repeat()`](https://einops.rocks/api/repeat/) to fuse steps 5–6 (assuming your array has a maximum of 26 dimensions, or otherwise you will run out of letters for naming its axes):

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet
from einops import reduce, repeat
import numpy as np

def local_average(m: np.ndarray, k: int | tuple[int]) -> np.ndarray:
    assert not np.any(np.asarray(m.shape) % k)  # As above
    k = (np.ones(m.ndim) * k).astype(int)  # Same as "patch" above
    assert m.ndim <= len(alphabet)  # Do we have d<=26 dimensions?
    abc = alphabet[:m.ndim]  # First d letters of the alphabet

    full = " ".join(f"({l}1 {l}2)" for l in abc)  # "(a1 a2) (b1 b2) …"
    reduced = " ".join(f"{l}1" for l in abc)  # "a1 b1 …"
    lengths = {f"{l}2": i for l, i in zip(abc, k)}  # {"a2": k[0], "b2": k[1] …}
    # 1–4. reduce(m, "(a1 a2) (b1 b2) … -> a1 b1 …", "mean", a2=k[0], b2=k[1], …)
    means = reduce(m.astype(float), f"{full} -> {reduced}", "mean", **lengths)
    # 5–6. repeat(means, "a1 b1 … -> (a1 a2) (b1 b2) …", a2=k[0], b2=k[1], …)
    return repeat(means, f"{reduced} -> {full}", **lengths)
```

I did not notice any significant differences in execution time though.

### Final thoughts

- I don't know your exact use case, but personally I would already stop after step 4 in the code, i.e. only calculate and return the mean for each grid cell rather than inflating to full array size again. The latter appears to be redundant to me.
- The resulting `local_average(m, k)` functions also work for `k` being a `d`-element tuple; try, for example, `k_demo = (2, 3, 3)`. In other words, your grid steps can be different for each dimension, as long as they divide the corresponding array shapes without remainder.